# Changing header button image and header text at runtime

Tags: android

I have a header common in all activities.

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/header_layout" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

<!-- home button -->
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/header_home_button"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_info" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

<!-- header text -->
<TextView android:id="@+id/header_title" android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Todays recipe :" android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However in different activities the title changes for textview and image for imageButton also changes. How to change them at runtime?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to get the both the Button and TextView by their id and set the image and text from your activity.

```
ImageButton _home  = (ImageButton)finndViewById(R.id.header_home_button);
_home.setImageResource(R.drawable.anyimage);


TextView _title  = (TextView )finndViewById(R.id.header_title);
_title.setText("Your title");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Activity file:

```
TextView tv_edit = (TextView)findViewByID(R.id.header_title);
ImageButton btn_image = (ImageButton)findViewByID(R.id.header_home_button);

tv_edit.settext("Your text");
btn_imagesetImageResource(R.id.myImage);
```